# Adding a pre-populated database in a jQuery Mobile Phonegap application

Tags: jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an application built as a native app in iPhone. The application used an SQLite database, which has 1000s of rows in it. Now I need to create an Android app using Phonegap. Actually, I am not aware about Phonegap or Android, but I know some HTML, CSS and JavaScript. So I have decided to make the app in Phonegap.

Now I want to integrate this database (SQLite) in my jQuery Mobile application. It was easy in the iPhone app, but I am little lost when I am looking for a solution in Phonegap. I have checked many tutorials on jQuery Mobile but none worked in the browser.

I am new in Phonegap and jQuery.

Comment: Can you tell me. What help exactly you need.

Comment: HI Aravinth, I have a already created database in sqlite. I want to use same database in the app. I don't want to add rows on the fly as the database has 1000s of rows.

Comment: check this one http://k4ml.github.io/android-phonegap-with-existing-sqlite-database.html and this also http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest including a file that returns a `JSON` string containing your data.

On initial load of the app check to see if the database has been populated and if not run a function to get the object and then load it into the database.

You can use a simple `$.get()` method and make use of the `HTML5` spec for `webSQL`.

Here is an example:

I start by creating a object called db -

```
var db;
dbHandler = {
    initialize: function() {
        db = window.openDatabase('appdb', '1.0', 'AppDB', 5000000);
        db.transaction(dbHandler.createDB, dbHandler.errorCB, dbHandler.checkDB);
    },
    createDB: function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _TABLE_NAME_ (itemID unique, someField, someOtherField)');
    },
    checkDB: function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM _TABLE_NAME_', [], dbHandler.checkDBcallBack, dbHandler.errorCB);
    },
    checkDBcallBack: function(tx, results) {
        if(results.rows.length > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $.get('local/file/with/json/object.json', function(data) {
                dbHandler.populateDB(JSON.parse(data));
            });
        }
    },
    populateDB: function(records) {
        var len = records;
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            for(var i =0; i < len; i++) {
                tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO _TABLE_NAME_ (someField, someOtherField) VALUES (?,?)', [], dbHandler.successCB, dbHandler.errorCB);
            }
        },
        dbHandler.errorCB,
        dbHandler.successCB);
    },
    errorCB: function(tx, err) {
        //console.log(err);
    },
    successCB: function(msg) {
        if(msg) {
            //navigator.notification.alert(msg);
        }
    }
};
```

Once the `deviceready` event has triggered call

```
dbHandler.initialize();
```

This may not work out of the box, but should be a good start to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. Please follow the steps below:

You already have a database in your ios app you can directly get the database files (you need `Databases.db` and `file__0/0000000000000001.db` files)

- For android, keep your prepopulated `Databases.db` and `file__0/0000000000000001.db` db in your root folder `android->asset` .
- Open your android project in your coder tool *(i am using eclipse)* and open `src->com.projectname->projectname.java` file.
- Please update the below code changes in your `projectname.java` file.

**sampleproj.java:**

```
    package com.pnms.sample;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import org.apache.cordova.*;

    public class sampleproj extends CordovaActivity 
    {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      //Try add the below try catch

        try
         {
           this.copy("Databases.db","/data/data/com.pnms.sample/app_database/");
           this.copy("0000000000000001.db","/data/data/com.pnms.sample/app_database/file__0/");
         }
         catch (IOException e)
         {
          e.printStackTrace();
          }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }

            //Prepopulate copy function
     void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException 
     {

      File CheckDirectory;
      CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
       if (!CheckDirectory.exists())
      { 
       CheckDirectory.mkdir();
      }

         InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
         OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder+file);

         // Transfer bytes from in to out
         byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
         int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
         in.close(); out.close();

       }
         }
```

**NOTE:** You need to add some *import, try catch function* and finally *Prepopulate copy function*

- Open your `database.db` file in some database viewer *(SQLite Manager)* and find the `DatabaseName & DisplayName`. You should mention these names in your javaScript `OpenDatabase` code.

Which would be like below *(My dbname= Database, Displayname=EventPortal)*

```
        .....
    function onDeviceReady()
    {

        db=window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "EventPortal", 100000);
        alert('db creating: '+db);
        db.transaction(createTable);
    }   
        .... and goes on...
```

Thats it. Now you can able to see your pre-populated database in your Database Location. Usually `/data/data/com.pnms.sample/app_database/..`